# Run command while simulating OS

Tags: docker, electron, grpc

I'm making an Electron app that I need to be cross-platform.
It requires gRPC to run. Except, to get the gRPC for the OS, as far as I know, I need to run the NPM command from that OS.
I.e. Since I'm using a Windows, the command `npm rebuild grpc --target=4.0.3 --runtime=electron --dist-url=https://atom.io/download/electron` will only get the gRPC binary for Windows, which is great for running the application on Windows - but not for the other OSs.

One way I thought to get around this problem is by using Docker, except, I don't know if it's actually possible, and if it is - I don't know how to do so.
I thought, if Docker is meant to run the application in an isolated environment - could I use it to make NPM download the gRPC binary for Linux & macOS?

Comment: I would recommend using any Electron version other than 4.0.x. Electron screwed up some binary versioning things there and as a result grpc does not ship binaries compatible with that version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the binaries for other platforms using the `--target_platform` option. To get Linux and MacOS binaries you want to use the values `linux` and `darwin`. When downloading the Linux binary you will also need to use the option `--target_libc=glib`.

For completeness, if you want to download Windows binaries from other platforms, the `--target_platform` value is `win32`. And if you want to download Windows or MacOS binaries from Linux, you need to pass the option `--target_libc=unknown`.

Comment: Well, I got an error: `node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.19.0/electron-v4.0-linux-x64-unknown.tar.gz `, what's the latest Electron version that the gRPC binaries that are compiled to it, support both Windows, Linux, and macOS?

Comment: As I said in my other comment, anything but Electron 4.0 will work. So you can use Electron 4.1, or Electron 5, or anything else.

Comment: Well, I [got a problem](https://i.imgur.com/rSpWDqS.png) while attempting to execute the command I put in my main post, except replacing `4.0.3` with `5.0.1`

Comment: After some Googling, I landed on a GitHub issue report, which led me to [this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc?project=grpc-testing). The question is now how to specifically pick a version using the NPM command.

Comment: The beginning of that error output will have more useful information than the end does.

Comment: Right now I'm attempting to solve the problem by downloading [.Net Framework 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15354)

Comment: After some Googling, landing [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/307), I think the problem isn't exactly according to the error, i.e. that I need .Net Framework 2.0 SDK - but rather I just need to install via Visual Studio the C++ features to have the C++ compiler.

Comment: The reason I said that is that you shouldn't need to build the library at all. There are binary files distributed for grpc. The beginning of the error output should show that it tried to download the file and why that failed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. When I first encountered this issue & started Googling, I simply arrived at the NPM command that I included in the main post, which solved the problem. Though now I need a different solution, like you said.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193736/discussion-between-avi12-and-murgatroid99).

Comment: After some digging, I discovered that all the `--target_platform` does is to change the [URL](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc?project=grpc-testing) that will be used to download the pre-compiled gRPC binary, and insert it to the project so it can be used seamlessly. Since the parameter only changes the platform part (as in `electron-v4.0-PLATFORM-x64-unknown.tar.gz`) - apparently there's no package name of Linux that is using `unknown`, but only `glibc`.

Comment: What is the way to change the `unknown` part to `glibc`?

Comment: I forgot about that part. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!